# Does the early 2014 MacBook Air use Thunderbolt 1 or Thunderbolt 2?

Tags: macbook-pro, dual-screen

I am considering purchasing a new MacBook Air (early 2014 edition). I'd like to drive two external monitors from the laptop.

Based on my reading the 2013 Air only supported [Thunderbolt 1 and therefore DisplayPort 1.1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/117288/1298). With the semi-model-refresh that occurred in early 2014 was the Thunderbolt controller updated to version 2 and therefore DisplayPort 1.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, The Early 2014 MacBook Air has Thunderbolt 1 and therefore DisplayPort 1.1.

Source : [Apple Support Page](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP700)

Comment: and regarding your intention to buy a MacBook : You should probably wait for the MacBook Pros to get TB2 first (buy them if you like) - and after that wait for the MacBook Airs to get TB2.

Answer (score 1):

Mid-2012 and later MacBook Airs do support two Thunderbolt displays (see [this document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5219) from Apple), but if you're not using Apple displays it's a bit more complicated.

You'll need to either invest in something like [this](http://www.zotacusa.com/zotac-mini-displayport-to-dual-hdmi-adaptor.html) Mini DisplayPort to dual HDMI adapter, a [Matrox DualHead2Go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/) or a [DisplayLink](http://www.displaylink.com/) USB adapter (those do have issues with newer Macs and Mavericks though, I believe).

Answer (score -1):

This [french article](http://www.macg.co/materiel/2014/04/le-macbook-air-est-thunderbolt-2-sur-le-papier-81694) says yes Thunderbolt 2 **but** :

- Apple markets it as a TB2.
- But the processor has only 6 PCIe lines :

  - 1 for the webcam
  - 1 for the wifi
  - 2 for the SSD

Leaving only 2 PCIe lines for the thunderbolt which is barely enough for the TB 1 specs (in terms of bandwidth).