# MacBookAir 2014 MiniDP to DP 2560x1440

Tags: display, displayport

Does anyone know if I can use the full resolution 2560x1440 of this DELL U2711
[http://www.amazon.com/Dell-UltraSharp-U2711-27-inch-Widescreen/dp/B0039648BO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0039648BO)

With MacBookAir early 2014,

using MiniDisplayPort (on MacBookAir) to DisplayPort (on monitor)

using this Kogan MiniDisplayPort to DisplayPort Male to male cable?
https://www.kogan.com/au/buy/mini-displayport-displayport-cable-male-male-12m/

According to the answer here on stackexchange, I should be able to
[What's the max resolution for mini DisplayPort connected to a 2013 MacBook Air?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/95606/whats-the-max-resolution-for-mini-displayport-connected-to-a-2013-macbook-air)

??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. According to MacTracker.app:

**External Resolution Up to 2560 by 1600 pixels.**

Personally, I would connect the MBA to the Dell over HDMI, and get the highest quality MDP dongle. Apple used to sell its own, but now sells a [Moshi Adaptor](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/HFQL2VC/A/moshi-mini-displayport-to-hdmi-adapter-4k?fnode=8b).

At my school, we use [Belkin Adaptors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004RHNJOG) sold  on Amazon (at this particular point in time) with a 66% discount price.

Comment: thanks, DELL U2711 HDMI officially only supports up to 1920x1200, but can be forced to display up to 2560x1600 http://superuser.com/questions/119755/hdmi-with-resolution-2560-x-1440-possible   But no info yet how to do this on OSX